# ¿Por qué este script no lee las variables que le paso con "read"?

Tags: bash, bucles, shell-script

Estoy haciendo un instalador de SLURM y creé un pequeño script para modificar el archivo /etc/hosts y así añadir las IPs. En realidad creé 2, uno que añade solo una IP+Hostname (que si funciona) y este que utiliza un loop para añadir tantas como se necesiten:

```
#!/bin/bash

archivohosts=/etc/hosts
echo "¿Cuantas Ips y Hostnames quieres añadir?"
echo "Escribe el numero por ejemplo 3"
echo ""
read FINAL

for x in $(seq 1 $FINAL)
do
    echo "Inserte la IP$x:"
    read ip0$x
    echo "Inserte el hostname$x:"
    read hostname0$x
    echo "$ip0$x      $hostname0$x" >> $archivohosts
    sleep 2
done

cat $archivohosts
```

Y lo que añade al archivo hosts es:

```
1    1

2    2

3    3
```

En vez de la IP1   Hostname1, etc.

Comment: Si necesitas agregar variables tras strings deberias poner `string{$variable}`, de lo contrario te puede suceder que no lea la variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trata de que quede así.

```
for x in $(seq 1 $FINAL)
do
    echo "Inserte la IP $x:"
    read ip0
    echo "Inserte el hostname $x:"
    read hostname0
    echo "$ip0      $hostname0" >> $archivohosts
done
```

Es decir, eliminando como sufijo la variable `$x` en cada variable como `hostname0` e `ip0`.

Comment: nótese que `$(seq $FINAL)` es lo mismo que `$(seq 1 $FINAL)`. Es decir, el 1 inicial es por defecto.